# What is a good practice to set machine specific folders in a project?

Tags: r

I have R projects that I need to work with on several machines. The problem is the input data files are huge (think around 100GB).

Say on machine A they are under: "`../ProjectAData`",
machine B (mac): "`/Volumes/ExternalDisk/Data/ProjectA`" and machine C (win): "`\\Server\Share\SomeStructure\ProjectA`"

I need to reference these files over and over. I kept messing around with environment variables or scripts that would check the hostname - however these all turned out quite fragile and I don't think it worthwhile to write a complex tool to achieve this.

I have the feeling there should be a cleaner way to do this.

Do you know any "best practice" or other simple solution?